# Error when trying to copy list to array

Tags: c#, arrays, list, error-handling

I always get error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.IndexOutOfRangeException' occurred in .exe
>       Additional information: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

```
public List<SomeObject> hCL = new List<SomeObject>();
SomeObject[] cl_ = clients.GetCLValue(1, 1);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
       SomeObject[] c = clients.GetCLValue(1, i).ToArray();
       c[i].LanguageId = i;                
       hCL.Add(c[i]);
    }
```

GetCLValue return list of data, but i cant move those data to array
Why those error always appear? Shouldn't c# have to create new object in which can be stored datas?

Comment: Collections are **zero**-based.

Comment: How to make collection non-zero based to work propriety

Comment: why make them non-zero based? why not use zero based index?

Comment: I dont know  that is why im here. show some example.

Comment: If you for some strange reason can't live without 1 based indices try this: `int zeroBasedIndex = my1BaseIndex - 1;` :|

Comment: just do: `int i = 0; i < 5` and `GetCLValue(1, i+1)`

Comment: thnx for help but i still get same error

Comment: ok, then show us `GetCLValue` method

Comment: it is service which return list of SomeObject

Comment: Also you are re creating the array inside the for loop

Comment: it is hard to understand an expected logic in your code, could you please then try to explain what do you want to do?

Comment: i just want to use values from GetCLValue inside new object (c), but every time when i run for loop it throw same error

Comment: ok, then please add the following line `Console.WriteLine("Array size: {0}; Index: {1}", c.Lenght, i)` between `SomeObject[] c = clients.GetCLValue(1, i).ToArray();` and `c[i].LanguageId = i;` and show us output

Comment: i is 1, and c is {locatoiontoservice.ServiceReference1.ServiceName[0]}

Comment: you should print `c.Lenght` instead of `c`.

Comment: does not it explain everything?

Comment: .... it seems that is explain ... thnx for help

Answer (score 1):

Why not just go

SomeObject[]  cl = hCL.ToArray() ;

Comment: and what to get empty array with empty converted list .... you need to put in SomeObject array method called GetCLValue

Comment: if you want an empty array of lets say 5 SomeObjects then: SomeObject[] cl = new SomeObject[5];

Comment: read my question before answer, i didn't search for empty objects hCL.ToArray() doesn't consist anything so copy those empty list to SomeObject array isn't right answer.